# Адаптивные блоки друг под другом

Tags: html, css, responsive

Помогите сделать адаптивные блоки как на этой картинке. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал так: 
HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6  col-xs-12">
      <div class="cnt"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="cnt"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6  col-xs-12">
      <div class="cnt"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="cnt"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.cnt {
  padding:20px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  overflow:hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 90px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  .cnt {
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
  .cnt {
    width: 471px;
    height: 452px;
    padding: 30px;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1170px) {
    .cnt {
        height: 380px;
    }
}
```

у меня они не так близко расположены как на картинке. В чем проблема?
Только учусь, поэтому помогите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите видео-уроки про grid-css и flex-box. Для адаптации изучите @media запросы

Comment: посмотрите еще раз вопрос. Я обновил со своим кодом. Спасибо.

Comment: Зайдите в инспектор кода, наведите на Ваши блоки и посмотрите, проблема будет сразу перед глазами.

Comment: @meine классно, спасибо! я убрал ширину и все заработало. Можете объяснить как сделать тогда фиксированную ширину и высоту, но чтобы все также осталось?